# BigQuery Select with Limit equivalent

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

does anyone know what is best in terms of performance for a query like this in BigQuery?

```
SELECT lastUpdated
FROM `test_db.test_dataset.Customers`
ORDER BY lastUpdated DESC
LIMIT 1
```

It works fine and gets the last result by date, however Im a bit concerned about the limit in BigQuery:

**Query complete (0.3 sec elapsed, 2.9 MB processed)**

Is there any way to run a similar query without spending that much processing?

Comment: AFAIK you'll always be billed for at least 10MB, so reducing this further won't save you any money.

Answer (score 1):

If you're concerned about "spending" please consider only 2 things matters in a BigQuery query:

1. How many columns are scanned? You can optimize by **selecting only the column that is definitely needed** for a query. Plus, if a column is RECORD type, **selecting only sub-column will also help**.
2. How many rows are scanned? Note that **"LIMIT/WHERE/ORDER BY" doesn't change how many rows will be scanned** in BigQuery. 2 things that can reduce rows scanned are **[partitioning](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables) and [clustering](https://medium.com/google-cloud/bigquery-optimized-cluster-your-tables-65e2f684594b)**. In your case, clustering by `lastUpdated` is definitely going to help when your table grows in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `MAX()` instead:

```
SELECT MAX(lastUpdated)
FROM `test_db.test_dataset.Customers`;
```

I find that `ORDER BY` in BigQuery is not always optimized for the parallel environment.  In any case, I think `MAX()` is clearer for what your query is doing.